# Blazor | Dependency Injection error: Cannot resolve scoped service

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am new to blazor, and ef core.
I need a parameter passed into a function on my DbContext, I have created a service that has an 'int' field, but I am struggling to inject this into the context... I'm not sure what I need to do here, everything I've tried still results in an error. Some help would be great...

I'm trying to inject the "*_cookieRepo*" into the code, but I cannot pass an additional parameter into the constructor, when i do i get the "Cannot resolve scoped services" error.

**Startup.cs:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        services.AddDbContextFactory<OlqtContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                        .LogTo(log => Debug.WriteLine(log),
                            new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name },
                            Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information)
                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

services.AddScoped<ICookieRepository, CookieRepository.CookieRepository>();
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
    public partial class OlqtContext :  DbContext 
    {
        private readonly  ICookieRepository _cookieRepository;
        public OlqtContext(DbContextOptions<OlqtContext> options, ICookieRepository cookieRepository)
            : base(options)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
_cookieRepository = cookieRepository;
            
        }
    }

 public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {

            var loginId = _cookieRepository.LoginId;

            var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            var modified = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted);

            foreach (var item in modified)
            {
                if (item.Entity is IAuditable entity)
                {

                    if (item.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        item.CurrentValues[nameof(IAuditable.CreatedByUserId)] = loginId;
                        item.CurrentValues[nameof(IAuditable.CreatedDate)] = dateTimeNow;
                    }
                    item.CurrentValues[nameof(IAuditable.LastModifiedByUserId)] = loginId;
                    item.CurrentValues[nameof(IAuditable.LastModifiedDate)] = dateTimeNow;
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Interface/Repo:

```
*Interface**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Olqt.CookieRepository
{
    public interface ICookieRepository
    {
        public int LoginId { get; set; }
    }
}


**Repo:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Olqt.CookieRepository
{
    public class CookieRepository : ICookieRepository
    {
        public int LoginId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
The login ID is set here, in the loginrepo I created.
```

public partial class LoginRepository : GenericRepository<Login, LoginDto>, ILoginRepository
{

```
    private readonly ICookieRepository _cookieRepository;
    public LoginRepository(IDbContextFactory<OlqtContext> dbFactory, IMapper mapper, ICookieRepository cookieRepository) : base(dbFactory, mapper, cookieRepository)
    {
        _cookieRepository = cookieRepository;
    }

    public async Task<LoginDto> VerifyLoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        
        using var _context = GetOlqtContext();
        LoginDto retval = null;
        var login = await _context.Logins.Where(x => x.UserName == username && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (login != null)
        {
            var ReturnLogin = new LoginDto
            {
                UserName = login.UserName,
                Password = login.Password,
                CreatedByUserId = login.LoginId
            };
            retval = ReturnLogin;
            _cookieRepository.LoginId = login.LoginId;
            
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

This is the error i receive:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Olqt.CookieRepository.ICookieRepository' from root provider.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)


    InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Olqt.CookieRepository.ICookieRepository' from root provider.
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
        lambda_method63(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactorySource<TContext>+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__1(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptions<TContext> _)
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory<TContext>.CreateDbContext()
        Olqt.Repository.Services.GenericRepository<T, T1>.GetOlqtContext() in GenericRepository.cs

                return _dbFactory.CreateDbContext();

Olqt.Repository.Services.GenericRepository<T, T1>.GetAllAsync() in GenericRepository.cs

                using var _context = GetOlqtContext();

Olqt.Server.Pages.Quote.Quote.OnInitializedAsync() in Quote.cs

                Quotes = (await QuoteRepository.GetAllAsync())

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(ref DiffContext diffContext, int oldStartIndex, int oldEndIndexExcl, int newStartIndex, int newEndIndexExcl)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, int componentId, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> oldTree, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> newTree)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11<TResult>+<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
Olqt.Server.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__35_1() in _Host.cshtml

            <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-InitialState="initialTokenState" />

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
Olqt.Server.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml

        Layout = null;

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: I did not get why you inject a repository in context constructor . Are you sure that is true? I have seen people use OnModelCreating for those stuff.

Comment: Not asking you to understand why, asking if you can help me do this. But, if you read I need one parameter to be passed to the "SaveChanges" function I have in there (the login ID) i created this middle layer to avoid a circular dependency. So any constructive advise? You edited your comment to be more constructive but honestly, like i mentioned i am new to this. Do you have any examples of what you're referring too?

Comment: Where are you getting the login ID from?

Comment: @Nkosi; I have added in the error. 

On the startup, if i change it to "AddSingleton" instead of "AddScoped" it works... But i need this to be scopped.

Comment: @JohnM; I am getting the login ID from the Database when the user logs in, then the ID is written to interface. This part works, it's just injecting it into there that is giving me a headache.

Comment: Cool "from root provider." is the important detail here that was clipped in the image. You are most likely trying to access/inject the DB while still in setup/configuration. There is no scope as there is no request. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok, @Nkosi the end goal is I need to pass the "LoginId" to the SaveChangesAsync function I have in the context, adding it in as a parameter in my eyes does not seem like the most efficient way to do this... But do you have any ideas how I can achieve this goal?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve. but we will need more context about the actual code to be able to provide the requested information. At present you are just showing disjointed snippets of the symptom of the problem for us to have an overall picture of the code being invoked.

Comment: Quick question. Are you planning on manually resolving the DbContext or just injecting it where needed?

Comment: Just injecting it where needed. @Nkosi. I am going to add more of the code in.

Comment: A service will only accept another service scoped at it's level or higher. The DBContextFactory is a Singleton, so only accepts other singleton services.  You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks @MrCakaShaunCurtis, that makes a ton of sense... I'm still learning so i guess i'll have to explore a different route to achieve this.

Comment: @Arkayik here is an idea. create a property on the context to store the id. After calling `CreateDbContext` set id based on injected repo. do your save and then dispose of the context. I base this on the additional code shown.

Comment: I think making it a Singleton will only work for a Single User. Blazor does not have usable Scopes, the main reason to use the DbFactory pattern. But your Repo has the same problem.